# How can i make an interface for a composite of styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to make an interface for a composite of styled-components:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Title = styled.div``
const TitleNumber = styled.div``
const TitleNumberDigit = styled.div``
const TitleName: React.ComponentType = styled.div``

interface IUiStepTitleNumber extends React.ComponentType {
    Digit: React.ComponentType
}

interface IUiStepTitle extends React.ComponentType {
    Number: IUiStepTitleNumber
    Name: React.ComponentType
}

const UiStepTitle : IUiStepTitle = Object.assign(Title, {
    Number: Object.assign(TitleNumber, {
        Digit: TitleNumberDigit,
    }),
    Name: TitleName,
})

export default UiStepTitle
```

For this use-case:

```
<UiStepTitle>
    <UiStepTitle.Number>
        <UiStepTitle.Number.Digit>
            {stepNumber}
        </UiStepTitle.Number.Digit>
    </UiStepTitle.Number>

    <UiStepTitle.Name>{stepTitle}</UiStepTitle.Name>
</UiStepTitle>
```

But i have an error from typescript

`An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members`

How to compose such interfaces correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is not to use a component as a namespace.

```
export const Title = styled.div``
export const TitleNumber = styled.div``
export const TitleNumberDigit = styled.div``
export const TitleName: React.ComponentType = styled.div``
```

and use it like

```
import { Title, TitleNumber, TitleNumberDigit, TitleName } from './Title' 

...


<Title>
    <TitleNumber>
        <TitleNumberDigit>
            {stepNumber}
        </TitleNumberDigit>
    </TitleNumber>
    <TitleName>{stepTitle}</TitleName>
</Title>
```

If you really have a use case where you want to provide the components via an interface, you can build your interface as follows:

```
interface Title {
  Body: FC<BodyProps>;
  Number: FC<NumberProps>;
 ...
}

const fancyTitle: Title = {
  Body: FancyTitle,
  Number: FancyNumber,
 ...
}

// dummy factory
export const createTitle = (): Title => fancyTitle;
```

use it like:

```
import { createTitle } from './Title'

const Title = createTitle();

(
  <Title.Body>
    <Title.Number>
      ...
    </Title.Number>
    ...
  </Title.Body>
);
```

Comment: When using several atomic components, we have to use specific names that we want to avoid.
for example
```
import { BlockCommentUserTitle, BlockCommentUserRating, BlockCommentUserRatingValue, BlockCommentUserRatingValueImage } from './BlockCommentUser'
import { BlockAuthorUserTitle, BlockAuthorUserRating, BlockAuthorUserRatingValue, BlockAuthorUserRatingValueImage } from './BlockAuthorUser'
```

Comment: we want this
```
import BlockCommentUser from './BlockCommentUser' 
BlockCommentUser.Title
BlockCommentUser.Rating
BlockCommentUser.Rating.Value.Image
```